# Collisions not working with tags in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to create a game where once you hit the 'repeat' symbol you have to return to the position of the first repeat symbol i.e [image]

once the player hits the "end-repeat sign" they'll return to the "begin-repeat sign" but only once then they'll continue the level, but for some reason the game won't register the symbols even when a rigidbody is added

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
        
        if(state != State.alive || collisionsDisabled){ return; }
        
        switch(collision.gameObject.tag){
            case "Win":
                print("win");
                StartSucessSequence();
                break;
            case "Lose":
                StartDeathSequence();
                break;
            case "StartRepeat":
                print("touched");
                OnTriggerEnter(other);
                break;
            default:
                StartDeathSequence();
                break;    
        }
    }

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
       // if startrepeat is touched go to endrepeat
       //for only once
        StartRepeat = GameObject.FindWithTag("StartRepeat");
        EndRepeat = GameObject.FindWithTag("EndRepeat");

       for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
           if(other.gameObject.tag == "StartRepeat") {
               other.transform.position = EndRepeat.transform.position;
               other.transform.rotation = EndRepeat.transform.rotation;
           }
       }
    }
```

my "Lose" tag is working perfectly, but not my "Win" or "StartRepeat"
[image]

I was thinking perhaps it's an issue with the Z-axis cause everything else is similar to the obstacle ("Lose" - which is the red notes)

*if anything else is needed please tell me*

Comment: ```OnCollisionEnter```/```OnTriggerEnter``` are for the 3D colliders.  See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to use a 2d rigidbody change your OnCollision and OnTrigger to 2d , then i suggest that you don't call OnTrigger by your own and create another method that contains the OnTrigger Code and use that instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've fixed the issue, I had to add a capsule collider, then switched everything for 2D collision and it started to read the objects that it was colliding with. I also unticked 'on trigger'. My 'lose' tag was working because my collaborator had a collision detector script on it